# build jar of spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have mvc app with struct:

```
-src
 |-main (here java files)
 |-resources (here only application.properties file)
 |-webapp
   |-css
   |-js
   |-img
   |(jsp files)
```

I have not .xml files(besides pom.xml).

I'm rining from idea(with java8) and all okey, application working good!
But when i try build .jar file and execute it, i have problem: when i'm trying to load any page of my web site, i get error(java7): `PWC6117: File "null" not found.`

If i use java8 i see this error:http://pastie.org/10430969

Is there any way to build jar wich will be work same as in idea?

And here is a part of my pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: @JBNizet, Thank you!